# Issue in, when hover on a link displays my list but not able to click on it

Tags: html, css

I am new for css and need some help here...
I have an example of nested list view...what i want is, when i hover on a link, the inner list should be visible.....i am done this with css but the problem is when i go to click on the elements of inner list, it gets again hide....see this http://jsfiddle.net/t7mdf/
So how do i keep visible the inner list till the pointer is on inner list...

So what i am missing in my css style...please advice me..
My code is as follows..

```
<ul class="main-menu">
<li>
    <a>First List</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a>Second List</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a>Third List</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS is
`.main-menu{list-style:none;}
.sub-menu{display:none;}
.main-menu a:hover + .sub-menu{display:block;}`

Answer (score 1):

add another css chuck of code:

```
.sub-menu:hover{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7mdf/2/)**

```
ul.main-menu{list-style:none;
}
.sub-menu{display:none;}
ul.main-menu li {
    position: relative;
}
ul.main-menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```